# How to use refresh token to obtain new access token on django-oauth-toolkit?

Tags: python, django, oauth

I am using [django-oauth-toolkit 0.7](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) in my Django project for providing Oauth2 through my website.

I have followed the steps [here](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.0/tutorial/tutorial_01.html) and successfully got the access token, but I am unable to get new `access token`(if the access token is expired) with the `refresh token`.

I am able to get the `access token` with [consumer client](http://django-oauth-toolkit.herokuapp.com/consumer/done/?access_token=ptFZlUVuw4xjHoS0lFbjZ6AZrFyvru&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=36000&refresh_token=N93i6XKwdGYaSn5lTEA9eQPc5aCvlr&scope=read%20write), but how can I get this with my url in my web site, because I am unable to see what parameters are going to my site when I try to get a new `access token` with `refresh token`.

My access and refresh tokens are like this:

```
{
  "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in":3920,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "refresh_token":"1/xEoDL4iW3cxlI7yDbSRFYNG01kVKM2C-259HOF2aQbI"
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 43):

To get a new `access_token`, by using your existing `refresh_token` you need to send a POST request to the same url you used to get the token in the first place (`/o/token/`, assuming the default url). The `grant_type` would now be `refresh_token`, and you also need to authenticate with your client credentials, since you were issued some.

To summarize:
`curl -X POST -d "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=<your_client_id>&client_secret=<your_client_secret>&refresh_token=<your_refresh_token>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/`

If you want more information, you can checkout this [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6%20link) to see the relevant section of the standard.

Comment: how are you securing the client secret of the oauth application if its a client side or mobile application ?

Comment: @AshishGupta You could tunnel the request through your own server. Eg: create a PHP script and pass the refresh token to it. The server knows the secret and sends this to the Reddit API, and passes the result back to the client, so the client never needs to know the secret.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the post request in POSTMAN. Or Try this, it worked for me:

```sh
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Basic your_application_id' -d 'refresh_token=your_refresh_token&grant_type=refresh_token' localhost:3000/o/token

{
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiVlx1MDAxNcKbwoNUwoonbFPCu8KhwrYiLCJpYXQiOjE0NDQyNjI4NjYsImV4cCI6MTQ0NDI2Mjg4Nn0.Dww7TC-d0teDAgsmKHw7bhF2THNichsE6rVJq9xu_2s",
    "expires_in":20,
    "refresh_token":"7fd15938c823cf58e78019bea2af142f9449696a"
}
```

try this [Link](https://auth0.com/learn/refresh-tokens/)

Answer (score 0):

To get a new `access_token` from `refresh_token` by URL you can use the below URL and pass data in params:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<refresh_token_here>&client_id=<your client id here>&client_secret=<your client secret here>
```

Once you generate a new `access_token` with the help of `refresh_token` then the old `access_token` will be expire.